# API call using data from Redux reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to do API request to the server using data from `Reducer` (Updated state) after I dispatch it. I would have done it in the Dispatcher if I have enough data, but I only send necessary data to dispatcher.

How should I do it ?

```js
/* Book list container*/
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
      books: state.bookApp.books    
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    // Calling change book title from component
    return {
      // Dispatch new title to the book list by it's id
      onChangeBookTitle: (id, newTitle) => {
        dispatch(updateBookTitle(id, newTitle))
      }
    }
}

// Connect redux to bookList component
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps, 
    mapDispatchToProps
)(BookList);


/* Book list action creator */
export const updateBookTitle = (id, newTitle) => {
  return {
    type: 'EDIT_BOOK_TITLE',
    title: newTitle
  }
};


/* Book list reducer */
// Assume there's already a book to update
const defaultState = {
  bookList: []
}

const bookApp = (state = defaultState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'EDIT_BOOK_TITLE' : {
        let newBookList;
        // Create new copy of booklist
        // Do some transformation
        // And voilaa... i got new book list
        return {...state, bookList: newBookList}  
        
        // This is the place where I want to do my API call, using the new BookList data
    }
    default: 
        return state;
}
```

Comment: Show us the portion of code where you want to accomplish this, and what you tried so far.

Comment: @G4bri3l , I added some codes, please take a look at it. I tried lot of things, but it got me nowhere, so if you have any solution for this, please do help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good use case for a thunk action creator:

```
export const updateBookTitle = (id, newTitle) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch({type : 'EDIT_BOOK_TITLE', title : newTitle});

        const updatedState = getState();        
        // read values from updated state and make an API call here     
    }
}
```

However, note that you ***should not*** do any API calls from a reducer!  That is absolutely against how Redux is supposed to be used.

Comment: wait, where is the getState come from ? is it from thunk ? also, is the `updatedState` always get the latest updated state, I meant, don't you need to wait for the `dispatch` to be completed first ?

Comment: Dispatching of plain actions is 100% synchronous, unless a middleware intercepts and delays the action. For this example, you can assume that as soon as `dispatch()` completes, the state has been updated.  Also, when you pass a function into `dispatch()`, the `redux-thunk` middleware will call your function and pass in `dispatch` and `getState` as arguments.  See https://daveceddia.com/what-is-a-thunk/ for more info, as well as the articles I have listed at https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/redux-side-effects.md .